# Issue while flattening PDF using PDF-lib in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf.js, pdf-annotations

I successfully created a fillable form using **PDF-lib** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib).

But I am getting following error while flattening it.

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): Failed to find page undefined for element mahesh_Signature_0

Here *mahesh_Signature_0* is a text field name.

This is my simple code for flattening it.

```js
const formPdfBytes = await fetch(file).then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(formPdfBytes)
const form = pdfDoc.getForm()
form.flatten()
```

How can I resolve this? Any alternate solution to flatten annotations of PDF in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

```
const someVar = await form.save();
then download, view from the array

My guess from snippet of code seen.

import { PDFDocument } from 'pdf-lib'

// This should be a Uint8Array or ArrayBuffer
// This data can be obtained in a number of different ways
// If your running in a Node environment, you could use fs.readFile()
// In the browser, you could make a fetch() call and use res.arrayBuffer()
const formPdfBytes = ...

// Load a PDF with form fields
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(formPdfBytes)

// Get the form containing all the fields
const form = pdfDoc.getForm()

// Fill the form's fields
form.getTextField('Text1').setText('Some Text');

form.getRadioGroup('Group2').select('Choice1');
form.getRadioGroup('Group3').select('Choice3');
form.getRadioGroup('Group4').select('Choice1');

form.getCheckBox('Check Box3').check();
form.getCheckBox('Check Box4').uncheck();

form.getDropdown('Dropdown7').select('Infinity');

form.getOptionList('List Box6').select('Honda');

// Flatten the form's fields
form.flatten();

// Serialize the PDFDocument to bytes (a Uint8Array)
const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save()
```

Comment: You shouldn't just copy-paste code, but also provide an answer on why your proposed solution is solving the problem exposed in the question.

Comment: what if getform isnt defined?